# Own Monad Transformer and lifting

Tags: haskell

```
data InterpreterM a = ExeInterpreter a | PropInterpreter a

newtype InterpreterMT m a = InterpreterMT { runInterpreterMT :: m (InterpreterM a) }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (InterpreterMT m) where
    return x = lift . return
    x >>= f = InterpreterMT $ do
        m <- runInterpreterMT x
        case m of
            (ExeInterpreter a) -> runInterpreterMT (f a) 

instance MonadTrans InterpreterMT where
    lift m = lift .  (ExeInterpreter m)
```

I've got error, and I don't know why:

```
Interpreter.hs:25:20:
    Couldn't match expected type `InterpreterMT m a'
                with actual type `a2 -> t1 m1 a2'
    In the expression: lift . return
    In an equation for `return': return x = lift . return
    In the instance declaration for `Monad (InterpreterMT m)'

Interpreter.hs:32:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `InterpreterMT m a'
                with actual type `a0 -> t0 m0 a1'
    In the expression: lift . (ExeInterpreter m)
    In an equation for `lift': lift m = lift . (ExeInterpreter m)
    In the instance declaration for `MonadTrans InterpreterMT'

Interpreter.hs:32:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> m0 a1'
                with actual type `InterpreterM (m a)'
    In the return type of a call of `ExeInterpreter'
    Probable cause: `ExeInterpreter' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(ExeInterpreter m)'
    In the expression: lift . (ExeInterpreter m)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What nicolas said. I didn't use the point-free style, so it might be a little bit easier to understand the types. You can look into example implementations to get a better feeling for transformers - [Control.Monad.Trans.Class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans)

```
data InterpreterM a = ExeInterpreter a
                    | PropInterpreter a

newtype InterpreterMT m a = InterpreterMT { runInterpreterMT :: m (InterpreterM a) }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (InterpreterMT m) where

--  return :: Monad m => a -> InterpreterMT m a
    return x = InterpreterMT $ (return . ExeInterpreter) x

-- or after you defined MonadTrans below
--  return x = lift . return $ x

--  (>>=) :: Monad m => InterpreterMT m a -> (a -> InterpreterMT m b) -> InterpreterMT m b
    (>>=) ima f = InterpreterMT $ do
        ia <- runInterpreterMT ima
        case ia of
            (ExeInterpreter  a) -> runInterpreterMT $ f a
            (PropInterpreter a) -> runInterpreterMT $ f a

instance MonadTrans InterpreterMT where

--  lift :: Monad m => m a -> InterpreterMT m a
    lift ma = InterpreterMT $ (return . ExeInterpreter) =<< ma
```

Comment: I think this entails that `InterpreterMT (return (PropInterpreter a)) >>= return` = `InterpreterMT (return (ExeInterpreter a))` which violates `x >>= return = x`

Comment: You are totally right. This is a simplified EitherT definition, but the important difference is that we have only one type parameter and not two like Either. One should change the case expression to `(PropInterpreter a) -> return (PropInterpreter a)`, but the typechecker throws an error because it can't match the expeced `InterpreterMT m b` with the `InterpreterMT m a`. Unfortunately I don't know a solution to this.

Comment: Right, I _think_  both cases should apply `f` to `a` and then go in and match again, assembling the result. In this answer to [his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187933/lift-monad-reader-local/37190716#37190716) I just reduce InterpreterMT to (a certain) Monoid + WriterT which has the advantage of being clear, but the answer is too complicated to be practical. I think the correct monad instance will effectively inline a monoid m + the monad instance for (m,)/WriterT m

Comment: `(return . ExeInterpreter) =<< ma` can be shortened to `fmap ExeInterpreter ma`.

Answer (score 4):

You dont seem to have any instance of MonadTrans in context so `lift` does not exist.

But more importantly, look at the type of the functions.
`x` is a value of type `a`  and `return x` needs to give an element of type `(InterpreterMT m) a`.

For this you need to use the data constructor `InterpreterMT` and give it a  `m (InterpreterM a)`

which means the body of return should be like

```
return . PropInterpreter $ x
```