# Lift Monad Reader local

Tags: haskell, newtype

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Error

data Context
data Memory 
data Functions

data InterpreterM a = ExeInterpreter a | PropInterpreter a

newtype InterpreterMT m a = InterpreterMT { runInterpreterMT :: m (InterpreterM a) }
type Interpreter = InterpreterMT (StateT (Memory, Functions) (ReaderT (Context, Context) (ErrorT String IO)))

data Stmt
data Stmts = EmptyStmts | Statements Stmt Stmts

interpretStmt :: Stmt -> Interpreter Context

interpreter :: Stmts -> Interpreter ()
interpreter EmptyStmts = return () 
interpreter (Statements s stmts) = do
    currEnv <- interpretStmt s
    local (\(prev, _) -> (prev, currEnv)) $ interpreter stmts
```

The problem is in last line- there is no lifting- I know it. But I don't know how to put lift here  because my experiments also gives me errors.
I am asking for help.

Comment: How about you tell us your experiments, including the errors they cause?

Comment: I guess, the problem is `Interpreter` not being a `Monad`.

Comment: Why do you find that `Interpreter` is not monad?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function such as `local` to be lifted to an inner monad you need the `map...T` class of functions.

For example, if you have a `WriterT [String] (ReaderT Int (Either String)) a` and you want to do run `something` with a different reader environment:

```
mapWriterT (local (+1)) something
```